# Почему аккумулятор садится?

Tags: этимология

Когда разряжается аккумулятор, говорят, что он *садится*. А почему? Почему не садится, например, разряженный барабан пистолета или банкомат, в котором кончились деньги?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У слова "садиться" основное значение - снижаться, делаться ниже, но без полной потери функциональности.

Садится у нас и самолёт, и птица. Садят, зарывая в землю, растения. Садится, делаясь более низким, голос. Проседает натянутый канат и напряжение в сети. Даже под арест и то сажают, так как раньше почти все места лишения свободы располагались в подвальных помещениях и ямах.

Севший аккумулятор ток даёт, но меньше (ниже), чем необходимо для полного функционирования, видимо поэтому глагол "садиться" и устоялся за этим прибором. Банкомат же и барабан пистолета, ниже после использования не становятся, поэтому они и не садятся.

Comment: >Садится у нас и самолёт, и птица  
 
Это совершенно другой смысл. 
Семантика "становиться ниже" здесь не катит, садиться означает Прикоснуться к земле. Аналогично - и с деревьями.

>Севший аккумулятор ток даёт, но меньше (ниже), чем необходимо для полного функционирования, видимо поэтому глагол "садиться" и устоялся за этим прибором.    

Фантазия Ваша. Ко всему прочему, Вы еще и физику не знаете. Ниже становится напряжение, а не ток.

Comment: 1. А касаясь земли самолёт и птица не снижаются? Когда отвечаешь на вопрос "почему", искать надо не различия, а общее.

Кстати, а закон Ома разве уже отменили, и при уменьшении напряжения в цепи, сила тока теперь возрастает? Спасибо, буду знать.

Comment: @behemothus, с аккумами реально все сложно - у них и отдаваемый ТОК уменьшается (при равном сопротивлении нагрузки), и напряжение на клеммах уменьшается. А вообще - растет внутреннее сопротивление источника. И все это в разной степени происходит для разных типов аккумуляторов.

Comment: >А касаясь земли самолёт и птица не снижаются? Когда отвечаешь на вопрос "почему", искать надо не различия, а общее.  
  
Зачем? 
А в отношении вопроса "почему", так в 90 случаях из 100 на него серьёзно отвечают только постоянные обитатели дурдома. Нет в языке причинно-следственных связей, когда дело касается этимологии. Писал уже об этом. 

Насчет закона Ома. Вы же сами его назвали. Ток зависит от сопротивления.  

>ТОК уменьшается (при равном сопротивлении нагрузки),  
  
Вот то-то и оно, что *при равном*. И если человек во главу угла ставит снижения тока, то это говорит о незнании основ.

Comment: 4. Причинно-следственные связи есть всегда, другое дело, что в такой сложной системе как язык, восстановить их как правило невозможно. Однако это не означает, что не стоит даже пытаться.  
Когда аккумулятор садится, электросопротивление не уменьшается, а следовательно со снижением напряжения сила тока тоже уменьшается. Слово же "ток" в отличии от "напряжения" не имеет ненужных омонимов и делает текст понятнее, пусть и с некоторым пренебрежением к терминологии физики. Но в конце концов товар в магазине мы тоже взвешиваем, а не измеряем массу.

Answer (score 4):

"Почему" это не вопрос. Потому, что так язык устроен.

У садиться/сесть есть значение

> Утратить силу, степень проявления; ослабнуть (об электрическом токе, паре, голосе и т.п.). Аккумулятор сел. Батарейки сели. Напряжение село. Что с тобой? - Голос сел
> (охрип).

БТС

Ничего похожего на разрядку барабана или банкомата. Они силу не потеряли, не ослабли...

В отношении конкретно батареек и прочего могу предположить, что это может быть связано с осадком, который сопровождал разрядку первых гальванических батарей. Хотя в паре с осевшим голосом эта версия несколько сомнительна.

Comment: Большой толковый словарь Кузнецова.

Comment: Да. А что, БТС - непонятно?